# Why doesn't CPP create a default deep-copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I don't understand why don't they have a copy constructor which makes a real multiple of the original.

As we know the main problem of the default copy  constructor is, that it performs a shallow copy. So that if there is a pointer it would only copy it's address but why doesn't it dereference the pointer a copies the content?
The main problem arises when having a dinamic allocation of memory . So that one can mistakenly delete it while having a pointer pointing to it, that's why we make our own copy constructors and do not use the default one.

But I can't get it, why doesn't CPP do it? Why doesn't it copy the content

Comment: If you use vectors/unique_ptr etc you normally can avoid manual memory management and avoid the need to implement [the big 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: What if the pointer points to the middle of an array?

Answer (score 11):

> As we know the main problem of the default copy constructor is, that it performs a shallow copy.

We don't know that.

> that's why we make our own copy constructors and do not use the default one.

In C++ you should almost never write your own copy constructor ([the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

> The main problem arises when having a dinamic allocation of memory . So that one can mistakenly delete it while having a pointer pointing to it

It's a non-problem. Why? Because in C++ we use the concept of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and we have tools in the standard library that solved all of the problems you see. In C++ you should never have to write explicit `new` and you should never have a raw pointer that is a owner. Use standard containers (e.g. `std::vector`) and smart pointers e.g. (`std::unique_ptr`).

> I don't understand why don't they have a copy constructor which makes a real multiple of the original

Because the compiler doesn't know what the copy-semantics of the object should be. That only the writer of the class knows. You can't know what the semantics of the pointer are. Is is a pointer that uniquely owns the memory resource? If so, was it acquired with `malloc`, `new`, `new[]`, or with something else? Does it share its ownership of the memory? Or is it simply pointing to an object it doesn't own? Since you cannot know any of this from the declaration/definition of a class, a compiler simply cannot implement "deep copy" automatically with raw pointers.

Except **it does**. It does implement deep copy by default, or shallow copy by default, or a combination of them. And it does so correctly. Remember when I told you to not use raw pointers for ownership? Use the appropriate abstractions (containers, smart pointers) and the default copy ctor will do exactly what it needs to do.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a pointer , the compiler has the content of the pointer which is an address, simply take the content in that address and copy it. Why can't you do it.

Comment: As to the first part of your answer, those are the reasons I saw written on the internet. For why we should make our own copy constructor

Comment: @bilanush copy it where? Thew copy you are creating contains a new pointer. To where should this pointer point to? To the old address - that's shallow copy. To a new address? What new address? How do you allocate space at this new address?

Comment: Simply allocate another space and create a pointer to contain that new address

Comment: @bilanush how do you allocate space? `new`, `new[]`, `malloc`, `kzalloc`?

Comment: I don't know CPP so well. I don't know how , this is their work to do it optimally. I am just asking about the idea of only doing a shallow copy. I saw on the internet ppl say you should make your own copy constructor if you got a dynamic allocation memory in your class because then you will get two pointers pointing on same place and have problem when one is deleted. If that is correct....I asked, then why really doesn't CPP help us by providing a real copy itself. Which copies content and not just adress

Comment: @bilanush you don't need to know c++ well to understand that there are multiple options to allocate memory and that you cannot know which one was used to get the original pointer. Also you cannot know if the pointer points to something that is not dynamically allocated. Or that it is just  a view. Re-read the answer.

Comment: @bilanush also, there are many many bad and very bad advices on the net about C++. Be very wary. Use a good book that teaches modern C++. You should never ever have a dynamically allocated memory that you manually manage (unless you are writing a library)

Answer (score 4):

> As we know the main problem of the default copy constructor is, that it performs a shallow copy.

Shallow copying is not a problem in general. It's only a problem if you want to make a deep copy, have a referential member, and assume the implicit copy constructor to do what you want.

Shallow copying is often useful and typically intentional.

> but why doesn't it dereference the pointer a copies the content?

Because where would the copy constructor store the copied object? Where should the pointer member point to?

The compiler cannot read your mind and cannot know whether you want to allocate memory, or how to allocate memory. If the compiler did allocate memory in an implicit function, then who would be responsible for its deletion? If the compiler deleted any pointers implicitly, that would be highly surprising when you intended to have non-owning pointers to something that must not be deleted.

> why can't the programmer be responsible for it?

Memory management is difficult enough as it is. At the moment it is at least manageable by following the simple rule: **You** `delete` everything that **you** `new`. If we introduce implicit allocations and impose the responsibility on the programmer to know of the existence of these implicit allocations, our job would become much harder.

Furthermore, a pointer can have an invalid value. In such cases indirecting through it would have undefined behaviour. And it is impossible to inspect the pointer to find out whether it is invalid. This would make the suggested implicit "deep copying" highly error prone.

Shallow implicit copying is the only sensible choice in a language that has manual memory management. Even in garbage collected languages this is generally the better choice.

> that's why we make our own copy constructors and do not use the default one.

*We* rarely write user declared copy constructors (outside of beginner courses). Those are mostly needed for classes whose sole purpose is to manage memory (or other resources) such as smart pointers. And we rarely need to write those, since the standard library offers the most general smart pointers and data structures out of the box.

> we should create our own copy constructor once we have a dynamic memory inside the class

Indeed, if your class manages dynamic memory, then it will need a custom copy constructor. But the typical solution is to not manage dynamic memory inside your class. See the paragraph above. Keep any and all memory allocations and other dynamic resources in a smart pointer or a container.

Comment: I saw in geeksforgeeks that we should create our own copy constructor once we have a dynamic memory inside the class , like a pointer which was declared with the new keyword. The only thing I don't understand is, why can't the CPP create a copy which does allocate memory and dereference the pointer to get the content and copy it. You said it can't be done because "then who would be responsible for its deletion? " . But I don't understand why can't the programmer be responsible for it? He copied it so he knows exactly that whatever pointer+allocation we had here we will have in the other object

Comment: Two things. 1. It goes FAR beyond just memory. Any resource should be adequately protected. 2. The compiler has no clue what you mean to do with the pointer. Computers just aren't smart enough to pick off context yet, and to be frank, neither are humans a lot of the time.

Comment: @bilanush see the additions in my edit. If you're still not convinced, feel free to create a language of your own with implicit deep copies without sacrificing the strengths that C++ has, and prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no way of knowing the meaning of the pointers it is supposed to "deep copy".

For example, does a float pointer point to a single float or to a C-style float array? If it is an array, what is the length of the array that it should copy? Please note that I am not talking about C++ style arrays (i.e. `std::array`).

If you want "deep copying" to be handled automatically, you can use [container classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) for data members that should be copied.

Comment: Why can't it dereference the content and get its copy placed somewhere else? It isn't possible for the CPP to dereference the content of an address? It doesn't know it's size per bytes?

Comment: @bilanush what if the pointer's not valid yet or has been rendered invalid by some other operation?

Comment: I don't understand. So what? You have it's address right? Simply get its content and multiply it. What do you mean by invalid? If the content is not anymore then you would probably not get any content by dereferencing it so its good

Comment: C++ style arrays (std::array) are aware of their own size, however this is not true for pointers to C style arrays. Such a pointer simply points to the first element of the array, without knowing its size. It is the responsibility of the programmer to know the C style array's size and to not access the array past its boundary. Therefore, only the first element of the array can (normally) be safely dereferenced if you don't know the array's size, provided the pointer to the start of the array is not NULL. However, there are exceptions to this.

Comment: @bilanush: Dereferencing an invalid pointer will result in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), i.e. your program will most likely crash.